# display image from Access database in .aspx

Tags: c#

Could you help me - I want each day to display same text with image from Access database where I stored text and image path. Text is going on the page, but for image I got only placeholder. I tried also with Handlers. I search through theses questions and nothing is exact what I want.
Here is code in C# I tried:

//image

```
    int IDImage = 0;

    upit = new baza.Upit("SELECT * FROM (Images INNER JOIN JoinImageText ON Images.IDImage = JoinImageText.IDImage) WHERE JoinImageText.IDText = " + IDText.ToString() + " ORDER BY LastTimeDisplayed, RND()");
    upit = new baza.Upit("SELECT * FROM (Images INNER JOIN JoinImageText ON Images.IDImage = JoinImageText.IDImage;

    if (upit.Reader.Read())
    {
        TextImage.Src = upit.Reader["image"].ToString();
        IDImage = Convert.ToInt32(upit.Reader["IDImage"]);
    }

    upit.Zatvori();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Handlers in ASP.Net.

This post from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126421/Image-Handling-In-ASP-NET) can help you in achieving your goal.

Comment: I read it, but I don't understand where I have to store procedure to get image. If the language isn't problem, I can put all my code to see it.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you're getting a placeholder you mean when the page renders in the browser?  If so, it means the path to the image is incorrect.  What image information are storing in the Access DB?  Image name only or image with path?  Make sure the path to the image is correct.

Make sure your     tag has the src attribute:

```
<img src="/images/someimage.jpg" alt="Image of something" height="64" width="64">
```

If you include the runat=server attribute, in code behind you could so something like:

`<img src="<%= Url.Content("~/database_value_for_image_path") %>" runat=server/>`.

The UrlHelper would resolve the relative path for you.

Or since you're using asp.net, consider the  asp:Image tag as well - [Image Class on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Are you using a server tag or plan html <img /> to render the image?  Can you post the code?  Also, can you store an absolute path in the db to see if it is a path issue?  For example, store 'http://localhost/Izreka/0001.jpg' instead of '~/Izreka/0001.jpg'.

Comment: I used server tag. And tried with 'localhost' without success.This is code:<br/><div class="izreka2">
                <p class="izrekatext">
                                        
                    <img class="izrekaslika" alt="slika" runat="server" id="IzrekaSlika" />
                        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="IzrekaText"></asp:Literal>
                        </p>
                <p class="izrekaautor" ><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="IzrekaAutor"></asp:Literal></p>
            </div><br/>

Comment: And this is in code behind: //slike
        int IDSlike = 0;

        upit = new baza.Upit("SELECT * FROM (Slika INNER JOIN VezaSlikeIzreke ON Slika.IDSlike = VezaSlikeIzreke.IDSlike) WHERE VezaSlikeIzreke.IDIzreke = " + IDIzreke.ToString() + " ORDER BY ZadnjiPutPrikazano, RND()");
        //upit = new baza.Upit("SELECT * FROM (Slika INNER JOIN VezaSlikeIzreke ON Slika.IDSlike = VezaSlikeIzreke.IDSlike) WHERE (VezaSlikeIzreke.IDIzreke = 773) ORDER BY Slika.ZadnjiPutPrikazano");

Comment: There's no src attribute in the img tag which is required in order to display the image.  If you're attempting to set this from code behind, what does the rendered tag look like?

Comment: And:if (upit.Reader.Read())
        {
            IzrekaSlika.Src = upit.Reader["slika"].ToString();
            IDSlike = Convert.ToInt32(upit.Reader["IDSlike"]);
        }

        upit.Zatvori();

Comment: I cuoldn't paste all in one comment. Complete tag is in these three comments. What can I put in src attribute?

Comment: See my edit in the answer section.  It displays the src attribute.

Comment: I tried asp:Image and src is also a problem. With <img> i got only one image from db. In my case what "~/datebase_value_for_image_path" means - "~/Izreka"? Where could I put it - in .asp or in .asp.cs (and where)?

Comment: Since you're storing the relative path in the db (i.e. '~/Izreka/0001.jpg'), perhaps you just need a helper to resolve the path.  For example, try `TextImage.Src = ResolveClientUrl(upit.Reader["image"].ToString());`

Comment: I got Error message CS1061: "'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image' does not contain a definition for 'Src' and no extension method 'Src' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" What and where I need to put in using dirctive or assembly reference?

Comment: I just referenced your original code.  If TextImage is an `<asp:Image>` control then you need to use a legitimate member.  For the image path, use the ImageUrl property [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.imageurl(v=vs.100).aspx)